# Inverting dictionary in python without using setdefault

Tags: python, dictionary

**Problem :** given a dictionary (each key has list as value!) invert it without using setdefault! you can assume the dictionary isnt empty and each value is represented as list.

I know there is an answer here in stackoverflow already! but they used setdefault and other imports ...

example:

**orig_dict :**

```
{"yossi":["harry potter", "lilo and stich"], "adam":["harry potter","catch-22"]}
```

**inverted_dict :**

```
{"harry potter":["adam","Bob"], "lilo and stich":["Bob"], "catch-22":["adam"]}
```

i have this code so far ...

```
def invert_dol(d):
    return dict((v, k) for k in d for v in d[k])
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: i tried to solve this! and i have my solution but not with "values represented as list" in dictionary ..

Comment: What does `setdefault` do? If you can explain that in words, it is almost a word-for-word translation into python.`if key not in dictionary:...`

Comment: The setdefault() method returns the value of the item with the specified key.

If the key does not exist, insert the key, with the specified value

Answer (score 0):

```py
    orig_dict = {"yossi":["harry potter", "lilo and stich"], "adam":["harry potter","catch-22"]}


    inverted_dict = dict()
    for k, v in orig_dict.items():
        for item in v:
            if item not in inverted_dict:
                inverted_dict[item]=[k]
            else:
                inverted_dict[item].append(k)   

    print(inverted_dict)

# {'harry potter': ['yossi', 'adam'], 'lilo and stich': ['yossi'], 'catch-22': ['adam']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing some nested list and dict comprehension. I made it like this:

```
orig_dict = {'yossi': ['harry potter', 'lilo and stich'], 'adam': ['harry potter', 'catch-22']}

def invert_dol(d):
    inverted_dict = {movie: [name for name, list_ in d.items() if movie in list_] \
        for k, v in d.items() for movie in v}
    return inverted_dict
```

Calling this function, passing `orig_dict` as a parameter outputs the following:

```
{'harry potter': ['yossi', 'adam'], 'lilo and stich': ['yossi'], 'catch-22': ['adam']}
```

(Note that there's no "bob" because in orig_dict there wasn't any)

Answer (score 0):

Where did `'Bob`' come from?

```
>>> {
    fave: [name for name in orig_dict.keys() if fave in orig_dict[name]] 
    for faves in orig_dict.values() for fave in faves
}
{'harry potter': ['yossi', 'adam'], 'lilo and stich': ['yossi'], 'catch-22': ['adam']}
```